# Is Swift type-inference contradicting itself here?

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6, swift-playground, xcode6-beta6

Here's my test code:

```
var myDict: [String: AnyObject] = ["k":"v"]

var a = myDict["k"]
var b = a as String

var c = myDict["k"] as String
```

Here's my Swift playground in Xcode6-beta6:

[image: Playground]

According to the rules of type inference, doesn't complaining about `c` logically contradict not-complaining about `b`?

Comment: Copy and paste the code into the question. If you want to show the playground as well fine. Personally I'm not going to type your code and deal with possible typos in order to provide an answer.

Comment: Oops, I didn't think about that. Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this is a bug.  Part of what is going on here is that `String` is not an object.  If you change the first line to:

```
var myDict: [String: Any] = ["k":"v"]
```

then everything is fine.  So, given that string is not an object, casting a variable of type `AnyObject?` to a `String` should definitely yield an error.  And, since the compiler has already decided that `a` is of type `AnyObject?` it should complain about casting `a` to a `String`.

Note that if you change the last line to:

```
var c = myDict["k"] as NSString
```

the error goes away supporting the notion that the issue is that `String` is not an object.  You get the same complaint if you put an `Int` as the value in the array and try to cast that to an `Int`.

**Update**:

So the plot thickens.  If you don't `import Foundation` or import something that imports Foundation, then you get additional errors.  Without Foundation:

[image]

So clearly some of this has to do with the dual nature of `String`s as non-objects and `NSString`s as objects and the ability to use `String`s as `NSString`s when `Foundation` is imported.

Comment: `String` is indeed not an object, it is a struct: really un-handy.

Comment: Ah yeah makes sense. So the bug is to let invalid programs run, not prevent valid programs from running.

Comment: But if you have: `["k":1]` there is going to be a crash.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the fact that `Dictionary` has *two* subscript overloads:

```
subscript (key: Key) -> Value?
subscript (i: DictionaryIndex<Key, Value>) -> (Key, Value) { get }
```

The first is the familiar one where you pass a key and it gives you an optional of the value; and you can use to set the value on a key.

The second one is less common. I believe `DictionaryIndex` is a kind of iterator into the dictionary, and you can use it as a subscript to directly get the key-value pair at that iterator.

When the compiler can't find an overload that matches (in this case, the first one doesn't match because it returns an optional, which cannot be cast to non-optional `String`), **it just picks one arbitrarily** (well, it seems arbitrary to me anyway) to show in the error. In this place, it picks the second one, which you don't recognize. That's why the error seems weird to you.

Comment: I don't think it's arbitrary; in my experience, the compiler carefully selects the wrong one :)

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
var c = myDict["k"] as AnyObject! as String   // "v"
```

To answer your question, the reason Swift complains could be that you are trying to do these two conversions in one go. Remember, the statement `var a = myDict["k"]` contains an implicit conversion already. The implied conversion is `AnyObject?`, so the above would also work like this:

```
var c = myDict["k"] as AnyObject? as String   // "v"
```

Note that the above would lead to a run time error if the key `"k"` where not defined. You would allow this to return `nil` by casting to `String?`.

Comment: Ok but surely the Swift language intends to have transitive type-downcasting semantics. So do you agree this is a compiler bug?

Comment: Surely Swift should have lot's of fixes to eliminate tons of casting.

Comment: If there is any chance that the value is not a `String` an `if let` is needed. `if let c = myDict["k"] as AnyObject! as? String`